# Pandas DataFrame - Recently registered clients orders count per registration day

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table **Clients** `['client_uuid', 'registered_at']` (['some_uuid', '2020-01-01']).
And an **Orders** table `['order_created_at', 'client_uuid']`.
I need to aggregate this data like this:

```
Column 1: Day (date)
Column 2: The number of clients, that registered that day, who have at least one order that day
Column 2: The number of orders made by clients who registered that day
Column 3: The numbers of all clients, who have at least one order that day
Column 3: The number of total orders by all clients in that day
```

Probably there is a solution using loops and so on, but I would like a more beautiful solution with maybe a groupby, agg functions. But I haven't ideas.

For example:
Orders Table

```
order_created_at | client_uuid
2020-01-01       | client1
2020-01-01       | client2
2020-01-01       | client2
2020-01-01       | client4
2020-01-02       | client2
2020-01-02       | client3
```

Clients Table

```
registered_at    | client_uuid
2020-01-01       | client1
2020-01-01       | client2
2020-01-02       | client3
```

Output Table

```
[date, new_clients_first_orders, new_clients_total_orders, total_clients, total_orders]
[2020-01-01, 2, 3, 3, 4]
[2020-01-02, 1, 1, 2, 2]
```

Comment: Some thing with `merge`. You should, however, include **specific** sample data and expected output.

Comment: Done. I want to know for each day, how many clients, who registered that day, made at least one order, and how many orders total they made that day. If TODAY there is 10 orders by 5 clients, and 4 orders of this 10 orders are made by 2 clients, who registered Today, output looks like [today, 2, 4, 5, 10]

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
pd.concat((orders.groupby('order_created_at')['client_uuid']
                 .agg(['count','nunique'])
                 .add_prefix('total_'),
           clients.groupby(['registered_at'])['client_uuid']
                 .agg(['count','nunique'])
                 .add_prefix('new_total_')
          ), axis=1
)
```

Output:

```
            total_count  total_nunique  new_total_count  new_total_nunique
2020-01-01            4              3                2                  2
2020-01-02            2              2                1                  1
```